# How do you open multiple videos with multiple subtitles in VLC from command-line?

Tags: command-line, video, vlc-media-player, subtitles

Usually, you can use this command to open a video with a subtitle in VLC, if it isn't detected automatically:
`vlc.exe path_to_video.mp4 --sub-file path_to_sub.srt`

But I want to open multiple videos, each with their own subtitle file. How do I do that?
Neither `vlc.exe video1.mp4 video2.mp4 --sub-file sub1.srt sub2.srt`
nor `vlc.exe video1.mp4 --sub-file sub1.srt video2.mp4 --sub-file sub2.srt` seem to work.

Comment: easiest would be to have the subtitles with the same name as the movie file (of course with diff extensions) and VLC (if you did not change any settings) will autoload the subtitle file and use it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible in this case since the path of the video file happens to be the absolute path (in the form of an MRL), or a symlink to the video-file.

Comment: do you know the filenames? if so, add all subtitles to one folder and add it to the VLC subtitle autodetection paths

Comment: @Zina Thanks, I'll try that out.